# In V20, is Elysium available to all vampires or just Camarilla ones?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

In earlier Vampire editions, Elysium was a sanctuary for Camarilla vampires, but we've been unable to find anything related to this in the V20 sourcebook.

Answer (score 11):

In principle, Elysium is for all vampires. In practice, Elysium is primarily a Camarilla construct that depends on the current threats facing the city, Prince, and Camarilla in that region.

A visiting Sabbat would be pretty unusual, and it would be best to work out their introduction in advance to avoid any “misunderstandings”.

> **Elysium:** A place where vampires may gather without fear of harm (although some Sects, such as the Sabbat, respect Elysium less than the Camarilla does). Elysium is commonly established in opera houses, theaters, museums, and other locations of culture. (V20, page 33)
>
> Every Prince grows increasingly terrified that one night the Sabbat will show up in his Elysium and murder him. (V20, page 42)

Comment: What this means about vampires that dwell in a city, but do not belong to the Camarilla, especially in cases on political rivals, like the Sabbat?

Comment: @DictumMortuum In my experience, if they have no animosity toward the Camarilla, non-Cam are welcome but looked at with some obvious suspicion. It’s the Sabbat that would need to tread carefully if they want to make a respectable appearance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget, **all** vampires belong to the Camarilla; it doesn't recognise dissent. The Camarilla governs all vampires, and considers its rules binding on all of them. Mere 'facts' and 'reality' don't factor into this!

That said, the details of how the Camarilla works are very campaign-dependent; it's assumed that every city is run at least slightly differently. There's plenty of scope for a Keeper of Elysium to bar vampires he disapproves of from Elysium, even for far lesser offences than being e.g. a member of the Sabbat.

Additionally, I would recommend that you don't rely on V20 for setting details - the book was intended to give comprehensive rules while leaving the Storyteller the freedom to decide what is canon, whether to use the metaplot, and so on. This intention was of course undermined by the many Onyx Path V20 sourcebooks, but the V20 corebook is best used either in conjunction with other setting material or just with your own understanding of the setting.

Comment: This answer could use references to the rules and source books.